# KornShell check using exit codes

Tags: shell, unix, grep, ksh

I am trying to create a KornShell (ksh) script to check the status of a process.
If the status is "pass", it will just echo "pass".
If the status is "fail", it will send an alert.

I can think of two methods:

1. Capture the process status into a temp file and search for the terms "pass" or "fail" in that file and action accordingly

   e.g.

   ```
   servicename > tmp.file
   grep pass tmp.file

   if exists, echo "pass"
   ```
2. Grep for "pass" or "fail" and use the exit code for other operations

   e.g.

   ```
   servicename | grep pass

   if exit $? = 0, echo "pass"

   else do something
   ```

What do you think of the above two approaches and how would you approach it?
Any code snippets would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does `servicename` set its exit status to non-zero on failure?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `servicename` returns a non-zero exit code on failure, you can do:

```
if servicename > /dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo pass
else
   # do something
fi
```

If `servicename` doesn't set its exit code correctly:

```
if servicename | grep -q pass
then
    echo pass
else
   # do something
fi
```